# Вернуть массив из функции dll (c++) в C#

Tags: c#, c++, массивы, dll

У меня есть функция которая заполняет массив в dll, все работает корректно - хорошо! Но мне надо каким-то образом вернуть этот массив или хотя бы строку с этим содержимым в C#, вот код:

```
DLLEXPORT void arr(char* data, char* buffer, int size){
    const std::string str = data;
    const std::string findStr = "<div>";
    int  bufSize = 100;
    char arr[100][100];
    container(str.c_str(),findStr.c_str(),160, arr,&bufSize);
    buffer=  new char[size];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bufSize; i++)
    {
        strcpy(buffer, arr[i]);
        //strcat(buffer, arr[i]);
        //strcat(buffer," @ ");
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<< buffer;
        cout<< "\n";
    }
}
```

Функция container - работает отлично, она заполняет массив arr, но вот в чем вопрос: мне надо его содержимое вернуть в C#. Переменная buffer инициализируется в шарпе и передается в в функцию arr() для заполнения массивом arr, но в шарп ничего не выводит, самое забавное что в cout<< buffer - она выводит!

P.S. container - функция которая ищет вхождения строк.

Вот делегат:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate void ValuesSTR(string data, string buffer, ref int size);
```

Вот вызов:

```
int size = 50000; 
string buffer = ""; 
ValuesSTR getNews = (ValuesSTR)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc, typeof(ValuesSTR)); 
getNews(data1, buffer, ref size);
```

Comment: Где код на шарпе?

Comment: Прикрепил!) Запамятовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема с кодом уже на уровне C++. Ваша функция не будет работать, даже если вы вызовете её из C++, потому что вы меняете `buffer`, игнорируя входное значение, и при этом ваше локальное значение никуда не возвращается. Вы передаёте *указатель по значению*. Разумеется, внутри самой функции `cout << buffer` работает, но за пределами этой функции ваш буфер будет недоступен.

Если вы хотите вернуть строку в C#, то можете предполагать такое использование, например:

1. Вызывающий код сам создаёт фуфер нужного размера (раз уж он передаёт размер).
2. Вызываемый код заполняет передаваемый буфер (а не создаёт свой собственный).

Создать буфер на стороне C# можно в виде `StringBuilder` с нужным `Capacity`. Соответственно, меняете `string buffer` на `StringBuidler buffer` в вашем делегате.

На стороне C++ заполняете переданный буфер, проверяя, что вы не выходите за отведённые границы.

И никаких `ref int size` — откуда это вообще? Вы передаёте число, а не указатель на число.

P. S. Не знаю, зачем вам понадобилось ковыряться с `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`. Есть же банальный способ с единственным атрибутом.

Comment: Да, все верно, уже кашу в голове себе заварил, а на самом деле все довольно структуризированно! А можете подсказать? Если мы передаем туда массив для заполнения? Как тут быть?

Comment: Точно так же выделять заранее.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на эту строку: `buffer=  new char[size];`.
Вы изменяете значение переданного в функцию указателя и, понятное дело, что снаружи (по старому адресу) нового содержимого не увидите.
Выделяйте необходимую память в вызывающем модуле и будет вам счастье.